# How to set input value with scrapy-splash?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm need to set input value in a form,the inputs remain empty after getting the response.

I have tried to set `assert(splash:wait(1))` to `assert(splash:wait(10))` in order to wait the page loading but it didn't work :

```
script ="""
 function main(splash,args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(1))
    local entries = splash:history()
    local last_response = entries[#entries].response 
    assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementById("email").value = 
    "1dfsdfsdf@dsfs.Com4"'))
    assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementById("email").value ="54654")
    local element = splash:select('#verification_code')
    local bounds = element:bounds()
    assert(element:mouse_click{x=bounds.width/2, y=bounds.height/2})
    assert(splash:wait(1))
    return {
          url = splash:url(),
          headers = last_response.headers,
          http_status = last_response.status,
          cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
          html = splash:html(),
          email = splash:select("#email").node.outerHTML,
          phone = splash:select("#phone").node.outerHTML
   }
end 
"""
```

The inputs remain empty:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"  value=""> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  value="" >
```

Comment: If you need this much functionality rather than mucking about with LUA scripts I'd just use Selenium. I would only stick with Splash if you absolutely need to since its a bit more lightweight. It would depend on how much data you have to obtain. I stay away from Splash all together for a few reasons. 1. its convoluted using LUA inside a python script. 2. the webkit version although lightweight used in splash is old and often black listed. I use splash only when I just need to retrieve a JS rendered value. If i need to navigate and do forms Selenium is the answer.

Comment: I'm also dealing with a website that uses reCaptcha V3 i keep getting rejected ,so i don't know wether to keep going with splash or just use selenium or pyppeteer knowing that this website has a huge traffic i'm affraid that when using selenium my requests are rejected because of that . What do you recommand please !

Comment: You're more likely to be rejected with splash since its based on an old version of web kit browser. Splash is easily detectable. If you are using Selenium there is no way for them to know except your basic finger print that comes with a default profile / the IPs you are using or if there is anything in the driver. I hear there is stuff in chrome driver. I've never been able to verify any claims of geckodriver revealing itself although it is easy to tell by reading the navigator JS object which you can randomize if you desire.

Comment: I tried to use selenium but it's really heavy i mean it took me 38 seconds just to get the website's url i'm trying to use pyppeteer is it a good choice ? The reCAPTCHA has also rejected me is there any pattern i should follow in order to not get rejected when surffing i mean scrolling the web page , make some clicks,i'm new to pyppeteer i still don't know that much about it but is it a good choice or selenium would be my saver ?

Comment: selenium is slow and heavy and like i said its a last resort you only want to use it if you have to. if you are still unable to scrape using selenium like i mentioned the navigator object. you just need to look at browser fingerprinting and accept that perhaps not every website you can scrape. however, usually for them to fully prevent scraping they have to harm their users in some way which is why most sites are scrapeable. i use splash only when i need to access something generated by JS but dont need lots of form control etc. is there even a reason you are trying to submit this form with js

Comment: I'm trying to prevent selenium from being detected but apparently selenium keeps screaming "I'm a BOT" any idea how to change the selenium's fingerprint i' tried a JS script to change the navigator webdriver ,plugins and languages but none worked .....! it's a V3